# 403 / Forbidden error when trying to run Rails 4 app with SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I am trying to get my Rails 4 working with SSL on a VPS with Ubuntu and NginX. I retrieved an SSL certificate from [StartSSL.com](http://www.startssl.com) and the installation on the server seems to have been successful.

However, I can't get my app to work with https. It only works with http at this moment.

When I try to access it in the browser through https I am getting this error:

`2014/06/04 18:05:56 [error] 23306#0: *3 "/home/rails/public/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 23.251.149.69, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "myapp.com"`

This would be my NGINX configuration file in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data; 
worker_processes 4; 
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http { 
  sendfile on; 
  tcp_nopush on; 
  tcp_nodelay on; 
  keepalive_timeout 65; 
  types_hash_max_size 2048; 
  server_tokens off;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types; 
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; 
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on; 
  gzip_disable "msie6"; 
  gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/comma-separated-values; 
  upstream app_server { server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0; }

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; 
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

  server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name myapp.com; 
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent; 
  }

  server { 
    listen 443; 
    server_name myapp.com; 
    root /home/rails/public;

    ssl on; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myapp.com.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myapp.com.key; 
  } 
}
```

What am I missing here and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this [over on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/permission-denied-to-rails-when-accessing-app-through-https), but I noticed it here too.

You have an `upstream` set but no `proxy_pass`. I assume you're using something like Unicorn to serve the app?  You probably need to adjust the server block listening on 443 to act as a reverse proxy for what ever is acting as an upstream server. Something like:

```
server { 
    listen 443; 
    server_name myapp.com; 
    root /home/rails/public;
    index index.htm index.html;


    ssl on; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myapp.com.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myapp.com.key; 

    location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    }

     location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. That's it. Thank you! One last thing: How can I forward any requests to `http` to `https` if possible?

Comment: Is that not working? The `rewrite` you have looks good to me.

Comment: No, when I enter `http://www.myapp.com` in the address bar, it stays that way and does not forward to `https://www.myapp.com` which would be nice.