# Elasticsearch no permission from searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

So, I've got a Rails 4 application on which I'm trying to set up elasticsearch using searchkick gem. I've got elasticsearch server running on an external device, so I'm setting up a connection in a simple initializer:

```
Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new( url: 'http://dajspisac-test:password@estest1.l.besty2.pl' ) if Rails.env.staging?
```

After deploy and deploy I'm getting an error when trying to reindex model:

```
       16: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
       15: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
       14: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
       13: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
       12: from (irb):1
       11: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/model.rb:59:in `searchkick_reindex'
       10: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/index.rb:200:in `reindex'
        9: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/index.rb:270:in `reindex_scope'
        8: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/index.rb:119:in `clean_indices'
        7: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/index.rb:106:in `all_indices'
        6: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/indices/get_alias.rb:43:in `get_alias'
        5: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/namespace/common.rb:25:in `perform_request'
        4: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:152:in `perform_request'
        3: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:24:in `perform_request'
        2: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:333:in `perform_request'
        1: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:205:in `__raise_transport_error'
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden ([403] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [indices:admin/aliases/get] and User [name=dajspisac-test, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [indices:admin/aliases/get] and User [name=dajspisac-test, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"},"status":403})
```

and also when trying to search:

```
       16: from (irb):1
       15: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/model.rb:43:in `searchkick_search'
       14: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick.rb:95:in `search'
       13: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick.rb:95:in `new'
       12: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/query.rb:43:in `initialize'
       11: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/query.rb:298:in `prepare'
       10: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/query.rb:298:in `each'
        9: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/query.rb:355:in `block in prepare'
        8: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick/query.rb:1033:in `below61?'
        7: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick.rb:78:in `server_below?'
        6: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.3/lib/searchkick.rb:74:in `server_version'
        5: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/info.rb:22:in `info'
        4: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:152:in `perform_request'
        3: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:24:in `perform_request'
        2: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:333:in `perform_request'
        1: from /home/dajspisac/dajspisac/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.5.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:205:in `__raise_transport_error'
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden ([403] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [cluster:monitor/main] and User [name=dajspisac-test, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [cluster:monitor/main] and User [name=dajspisac-test, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"},"status":403})
```

Yep, 403 speaks for itself, but when I'm doing simple test request from the same server machine, with same credentials to same index i'm getting what I asked for:

```
dajspisac@dajspisac-test:~$ http --auth dajspisac-test:password --pretty all GET http://estest1.l.besty2.pl:9200/dajspisac.test1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 258
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
    "dajspisac.test1": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1587330576604",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "dajspisac.test1",
                "uuid": "DDazlfIXSxakFJeu3rjD9A",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7040299",
                    "upgraded": "7060199"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and also for PUT:

```
dajspisac@dajspisac-test:~$ http --auth dajspisac-test:password --pretty all PUT http://estest1.l.besty2.pl:9200/dajspisac.test1/_doc/1 name=janekg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 144
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
    "_id": "1",
    "_index": "dajspisac.test1",
    "_primary_term": 4,
    "_seq_no": 1,
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 2,
        "total": 2
    },
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_version": 2,
    "result": "updated"
}
```

what I'm doing wrong, or what I set up incorrectly?

EDIT

of course, it's not auth error because setting up wrong user/pass gives 401

Comment: I assume that you are on the same machine. I would suggest you do two things to debug:
1. Try to send the request in ruby client with user password separately. `Elasticsearch::Client.new hosts: [ {host: 'localhost', port: '9200', user: 'my_username', password: 'my_password', scheme: 'http'}]`

2. Use tcpdump or Wireshark to see the difference in the headers of both scenarios.

Comment: Have you added a IAM role

Comment: try this [403 / Forbidden error when trying to run Rails 4 app with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042897/403-forbidden-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-4-app-with-ssl)